# Trying to print a custom element from a site

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, element

I have these elements

```
<button class="PurchaseButton reseller-purchase-button btn-min-width btn-buy-md ng-binding" data-button-type="reseller" data-expected-price="499" data-expected-seller-id="1848858135" data-seller-name="FroggyTheSaviour" data-userasset-id="881646002" data-product-id="11837918" data-item-id="76692866" data-item-name="Aqueous Egg of River Riding" data-asset-type="Hat" data-bc-requirement="0" data-expected-currency="1" ng-hide="resaleRecord.seller.id === $ctrl.authenticatedUser.id" ng-bind="'Action.Buy' | translate">Buy</button>
```

I want to extract

`data-expected-price`, `data-expected-seller-id`, and `data-product-id="11837918`

How would I do this?

I tried :

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')
            t = soup.find("button", {"class": "PurchaseButton reseller-purchase-button btn-min-width btn-buy-md ng-binding"})['data-expected-price'].text
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS selector `[data-expected-price]` to select tag that contains attribute `data-expected-price=...`. Similar for other attributes, for example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


txt = '''<button class="PurchaseButton reseller-purchase-button btn-min-width btn-buy-md ng-binding" data-button-type="reseller" data-expected-price="499" data-expected-seller-id="1848858135" data-seller-name="FroggyTheSaviour" data-userasset-id="881646002" data-product-id="11837918" data-item-id="76692866" data-item-name="Aqueous Egg of River Riding" data-asset-type="Hat" data-bc-requirement="0" data-expected-currency="1" ng-hide="resaleRecord.seller.id === $ctrl.authenticatedUser.id" ng-bind="'Action.Buy' | translate">Buy</button>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

data_expected_price = soup.select_one('[data-expected-price]')['data-expected-price']
data_expected_seller_id = soup.select_one('[data-expected-seller-id]')['data-expected-seller-id']
data_product_id = soup.select_one('[data-product-id]')['data-product-id']

print(data_expected_price)
print(data_expected_seller_id)
print(data_product_id)
```

Prints:

```
499
1848858135
11837918
```

---

EDIT: To load the data from URL, you can do for example:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.roblox.com/catalog/74939534/St-Patricks-Day-2012'

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

data_expected_price = soup.select_one('[data-expected-price]')['data-expected-price']
data_expected_seller_id = soup.select_one('[data-expected-seller-id]')['data-expected-seller-id']
data_product_id = soup.select_one('[data-product-id]')['data-product-id']

print(data_expected_price)
print(data_expected_seller_id)
print(data_product_id)
```

Prints:

```
502
175785764
11549631
```

Comment: it gets it from a variable here how would i get it from a url like https://www.roblox.com/catalog/74939534/St-Patricks-Day-2012

Comment: i also tried this with data_userasset_id = soup.select_one('[data-userasset-id]')['data-userasset-id'] but for some reason  it just prints nothing, even tho its the correct element name

Comment: do you have any idea why?

Comment: @Max Try `data_userasset_id = soup.select_one('[data-lowest-private-sale-userasset-id]')['data-lowest-private-sale-userasset-id']`

Comment: that works thanks very much also i admire you that you always help people